# Event bubbling and Event Propagation with react hooks

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dom-events

I have a handler that toggles a state that determines whether a popover is open or not. To toggle, there is an <span> element that has an onClick. Furthermore, I also have a hook that sets the state of the same popover to false if you click anywhere else on the window. So when I click the asterisk (*) the state first goes to false, because of the hook changing the state, then to true on the same click because of the asterisk(so it does not close).

I've looked at event.stopPropagation() but either I'm fundamentally not understanding it or implementing it wrong.

Here is my code:

```
const [openDisclaimerView, setOpenDisclaimerView] = useState(false);

const handleShowDisclaimerView = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLSpanElement, MouseEvent>) => {
  console.log('clicked', event);
  event.stopPropagation();
  setOpenDisclaimerView(!openDisclaimerView);
};

return (
  <>
    {formCompleted && srp != null && (
      <div className={styles.totalSRP}>
        <Typography variant="legal1">
          {srpText}
          <span onClick={e => handleShowDisclaimerView(e)}>*</span> ${srp}
        </Typography>
      </div>
    )}
  </>
);
```

```
<DisclaimerPopover isOpen={openDisclaimerView} onClose={() => setOpenDisclaimerView(false)} disclaimers={totalSrpDisclaimer ? [totalSrpDisclaimer] : []} />
```

```
interface DisclaimerPopoverProps {
  isOpen?: boolean;
  onClose: () => void;
  disclaimers: Disclaimer[];
  priceBarWidth?: number;
}

const DisclaimerPopover = ({ isOpen, onClose, disclaimers, priceBarWidth }: DisclaimerPopoverProps) => {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  useOutsideClick(ref, onClose); // here is the hook

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!ref.current) {
      return;
    }
    const disclaimerList = ref.current.querySelector(`ul.${styles.disclaimerList}`);
    const topGradient = ref.current.querySelector(`.${styles.topGradient}`) as HTMLElement;
    const bottomGradient = ref.current.querySelector(`.${styles.bottomGradient}`) as HTMLElement;

    const handleScroll = () => {
      if (!disclaimerList) {
        return;
      }
      const { scrollTop, scrollHeight, clientHeight } = disclaimerList;
      topGradient.style.opacity = `${scrollPercentage * 0.9}`;
      bottomGradient.style.opacity = `${1 - scrollPercentage * 0.9}`;
    };

    disclaimerList?.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

    return () => {
      disclaimerList?.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <section ref={ref} className={cx(styles.disclaimerBox, isOpen && styles.isOpen)} style={priceBarWidth ? { width: `${priceBarWidth}px` } : {}}>
      <div className={cx(styles.disclaimerBoxGradient, styles.topGradient)} style={{ opacity: 0 }} />
      <ul className={cx(styles.disclaimerList)}>
        {disclaimers?.map(disclaimer => (
          <li key={disclaimer.id} className={cx(styles.disclaimerItem)}>
            {disclaimer.description}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <button className={cx(styles.closeButton)} aria-label="close overlay" onClick={onClose} />
      <div className={cx(styles.disclaimerBoxGradient, styles.bottomGradient)} style={{ opacity: 1 }} />
    </section>
  );
};

export default DisclaimerPopover;
```

```
export const useOutsideClick = (ref: RefObject<HTMLElement>, callback: () => void) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleClickOutside = (event: MouseEvent) => {
      if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(event.target as Node)) {
        callback();
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);
    };
  }, [ref, callback]);
};
```